# Pre-Emptive Swift Animation Object Move - Confusing

Tags: swift, animation

Good day,

I have a very simple animation function, that drops a button by 200.

However, I discover that before the animation begins, the object is moved up (-) by 200!  Therefore, after the animation, the button is back where it started.

I tried to set self.button1.center = self.view.center in viewDidAppear before calling the function.

```
func dropStep(){

UIView.animate(withDuration: 6, animations: {

    self.button1.center.y += 200
}, completion: nil)

}
```

I expected the animation to start from where it is intended (at the center of the view) and not pre-emptively shifted up by 200 points.

Comment: How are you calling `dropStep`? i.e what did you do before calling it? Where did you call it?

Comment: if you have constraints, you should animate them, but not a frame

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik Hi Alexandr.  You raise an interesting point.  In swift, is it generally better to animate constraints, and not objects directly (like I did)?  Or are they somehow tied together that it does not matter. Thanks

Comment: if you use constraints any frame changes will be ignored, change constraint.constant, in animation block use view.layoutIfNeeded()

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
func dropStep(){
    button1.center = self.view.center
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 6, animations: {
        self.button1.center.y += 200
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: what is the difference of your answer from question?

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik Set the initial value of button1.center inside the dropStep() instead of somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I could not genuinely find the reason behind this.

However, this was an app that was used and reused to learn animations, so maybe somehow the object referencing outlets or some sort of hidden reference was messed up, such that the app behaved funny.

Therefore, I created a new app with virtually the same code, and it behaved as expected.  Thanks anyway for your help.